# Problems with an accordion menu using jquery and PHP to show 'active' links and keep menu slider open on current page

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

With my very little knowledge of jQuery and PHP, I have almost accomplished an accordion menu where the links display as 'active' when the active page is open, and the slider menu stays open on the correct section when on the active page.

I have added some php to the bottom links. The child links display as active when on the active page. However the parent element does not, and also closes itself.

I'd really appreciate any help!!!

Here's my code as it stands:

```
<ul id="accordion">    
<ul class="parent">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="slide">CMS</a>

        <ul class="child">
            <li><a href="/learn/intro-to-cms">Intro to CMS</a></li>
            <li><a href="/learn/specific-cms">Specific CMS</a></li> 
            <li><a href="/learn/installing-a-cms">Installing a CMS</a></li> 
        </ul>

     </li>
</ul>

<ul class="parent">
        <li>
            <?php
            if ($this_page=="Customising-Google-Forms" || $this_page=="Web-Event-Notes"){
            echo "<a href=\"#\" class=\"slide current\">Other</a>";
            }else{
            echo "<a href=\"#\" class=\"slide\">Other</a>";
            }
            ?>

        <ul class="child">
            <?php
            if ($this_page=="Customising-Google-Forms"){
            echo "<li class=\"current\"><a href=\"/learn/customising-google-forms\">Customising-google-forms</a></li>";
            }else{
            echo "<li><a href=\"/learn/customising-google-forms\">Customising Google Forms</a></li>";
            }
            ?>
            <?php
            if ($this_page=="Web-Event-Notes"){
            echo "<li class=\"current\"><a href=\"/learn/web-event-notes\">Web Event Notes</a></li>";
            }else{
            echo "<li><a href=\"/learn/web-event-notes<\">Web-Event-Notes</a></li>";
            }
            ?>
        </ul>

     </li>
</ul>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
// hide all links on load
$('ul.child').hide();
// for image
// $("a.slide:first").css("background-image","url('path')");

$('ul.parent a.slide').click(function(){
    $('ul.parent a.slide').css("color","#000");

    $('ul.parent a.slide').hover(function(){
        $(this).css("color","#ef492f");
    });

    $('ul.parent a.slide').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css("color","#000");
    });

    $(this).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css("color","#000");
    });

    $(this).css("color","#000");


    // slide all up
    $('ul.child').slideUp('slow');

    // show the links of current heading
    $(this).next().find('a').show();

    // slide down current heading
    $(this).next().slideDown('fast');

    // prevent default action
    return false;
});

if($("ul li a").hasClass("current")) {
$(this).closest("ul").slideDown("fast") //open the menu
}

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best way to accomplish this is by making a PHP array that contains the links and then build a html menu out of it. In this way PHP can control which of the links will hold the 'current' class based on the url parameters. The last step will be jquery to just grab the '.current' listitem and make it visible. The below may seem like a lot of work, but when you get it, it will be powerful and reusable :)

```
//Grab the page parameter somehow.. below = example
$page = $_GET['page'];

//Build menu array containing links and subs
$items = Array( 
    //highest level
    'cms' => Array(
        'title' => 'CMS',
        //Array containing submenu items for cms
        'subs' => Array(
            'intro-to-cms' => Array('title' => 'Intro to CMS'),
            'specific-cms' => Array('title' => 'Specific CMS'),
            'installing-a-cms' => Array('title' => 'Installing a CMS')
        ),
    )
);

//Display the menu
echo navlinks($items, $page);

/**
 * Recursive function creates a navigation out of an array
 * @param type $items
 * @return string containing navigationlist
 */
function navlinks($items, $page=false)
{
  $html = '<ul>';
  foreach ($items AS $uri => $info) {
    //Check if the pagename is the same as the link name and set it to current when it is
    $html .= '<li'.($info['title'] == $page ? ' class="current"' : '').'>';
    echo '  <a href="' . $uri . '">' . $info['title'] . '</a>';
    //If the link has a sub array, recurse this function to build another list in this listitem
    if (isset($info['subs']) && is_array($info['subs'])) {
      $html .= navlinks($info['subs']);
    }
    $html .= '</li>';
  }
  $html .= '</ul>';
  return $html;
}
```